# Как запустить виндовс через GRUB

Tags: linux, windows, grub

Параллельно стояла вин10 и убунта. По какой—то причине сдох загрузчик. К сожалению, не понимаю как исправить текущую проблему. Из статей на похожую тему понял, что нужно попытаться передать загрузку ОС следующему загрузчику, но не получается это сделать.

Наверняка я плохо сформулировал вопрос и дал мало вводных, буду очень рад если напишите каких вводных не хватает.  [image: Пока прикрепляю последнюю ошибку из консоли и последний список команд]

Comment: Самый простой способ - сделай флешку с виндой и запусти с неё восстановление загрузки

Comment: @eri понял, спасибо. А есть ли шансы это без флешки сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Решил. Зашел в биос и поменял загрузчик местами